What is the name of the movie with a giant at night?
I had a discussion with someone with a movie interest, and from that talk, it triggered a memory. I could not place a name on this film, and it has these following elements.
It is set at night time, and shows a hillside in or near the background, so it is on planet Earth. This discounts a number of films similar to Forbidden Planet which I don't think matches.
Another clue is that it has power lines that are tripped by a giant. I'm not sure if it is an invisible being, but it definitely outlines a giant. EDIT: I learned it is a human figure. The movie is in black and white from the older films of the 70s.
I am thinking it could be one of those older movies like late 70s, 80s or 90s. EDIT: Definitely in the 70s; it is in black and white context.
Any help is appreciated.

I think you need to give some more details, but is there a chance that you are looking for The Iron Giant?

Could also be "The Day The Earth Stood Still" from 1951: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still

Pardon for my lack of response/delay. I converse with my film goer to verify the details. I have edited the details given...

@FranciscoV. There's no giant in The Day the Earth Stood Still

Do you have anything else to go on? This seems like something that might happen in a lot of 'giant monster' b-movies (For examples, these scenes in War of the Colossal Beast and Attack of the 50 Foot Woman).

@Usernew “ Gort is a large, seamless robot apparently constructed from a single piece of "flexible metal". He was portrayed by seven-foot, seven-inch (231 cm)-tall actor Lock Martin" - For a small Person like me, this IS a giant :-)

@FranciscoV. that makes sense. :)

How about Big Friendly Giant? Not sure if they had an older version of the movie.

Iron Giant (1999)
Here is the scene you are referring to:


Sorry I would say yes but my film goer confirmed it is a black and white with a human giant not a robot giant and I have edit the original information to supply more clues.

@user1924393 Do check this IMDB list and tell me if you find it.

At the moment I am stumped as to how I could use multiple keywords in IMDB given only accepts one keyword at a time.

@user1924393 Did you find the movie in the list or not?

Black-and-white suggests to me 'The Colossal Man', but that is from the '50s not the '70s.

That looked like an accurate answer to me.  Color movies starting becoming commonplace in the 50's.
